# Background image not showing up in span tag

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble with a span tag showing a background image in the latest FF on windows 7.
It seems to work and show everything fine in earlier FF, Chrome, Safari and IE but handheld devices and windows 7 it seems to fail.

Sorry if this seems vague I just cant figure it out, the images were originally pngs with no height specified and ive since made them gifs and applied a height.

```
<span class="design">Design Viz</span>
<style>
.design  {
    background:url(_includes/images/agenda-design.gif) no-repeat top left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 17px;
    padding-left:25px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Just a fast guess, but you really need to have your url in '' (so it's url('_includes/images/agenda-design.gif')

Comment: I did, Ive stripped it out before posting it on here as its a client.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The background-image CSS property only puts an image as the background. The width and height of an object is always defined either by static settings via CSS/inline styling, or by the actual size of the content displayed in it.
In your case, since you haven't added any content between your tags, its x/y dimensions will be 0, but there is no bug with the background. It's there, only you can't see it unless you define (somehow) a size for the element.

```
<span class="design">Design Viz</span>
.design  {
padding-left:25px;
background:url(_includes/images/agenda-design.gif) no-repeat top left;
display: inline-block;
height: 17px;
width: 50px;
}
```

Where 50 can be any helpful value suited for your case.

Comment: I have content between my tags thought, 'Design Viz'?

Comment: Span's height and display were key factors I was struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

display:inline-block; is not supported by IE7. You can fix it by adding:

```
.design  {
    padding-left:25px;
    background:url(_includes/images/agenda-design.gif) no-repeat top left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 17px;
    width: 50px;
    zoom: 1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set attributes `no-repeat top left` if you declare background-image. In `background-image` you must only set the link to your image.

Or you could use `background` like this:

```
background: url(...) no-repeat top left
```

Answer (score 0):

use padding like

```
 padding-left:25px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add width: 17px to your css style too (or whatever width it is)

Comment: But the class is applied to multiple words all varying in length so I cant set a specific width...

Comment: well unfortunately you will have to have a width or something within the span that gives it width such as a transparent gif.