# How to display an image using an img tag and css and class instead of src attribute

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have to set the image of an img tag from the css. This is because both the company requirement and the class in the img tag changes dynamically. So, the following is my code for the img tag and the accompanying css. Since I am using Kendo UI, the values for class and title will be set from a webservice

```
    <img data-bind='attr: { class: exportPriorityIcon, title:   exportPriority }'/>

.priority-low {
    background-image: url('Images/export/priority_low.jpg');
}

.priority-medium {
    background-image: url('Images/export/priority_med.jpg');
}


So, the value exportPriorityIcon can be either priority-low  or priority-medium  as determined dynamically during run time. The value of title will be either "low" or "medium"
```

The image is displayed. But the string value for the title is displayed on top of it with a square around it. If I removed the title attribute from the img tag, no image displayed.

Comment: I have found a partial solution based upon this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582205/background-image-not-showing-up-in-span-tag . The problem now is that there is a border around the image. In the css I tried, border:0 still the border is displayed. The css code is given below:<span class="design">Design Viz</span>
.priority-low  {
padding-left:25px;
background:url(_includes/images/agenda-design.gif) no-repeat top left;
display: inline-block;
height: 17px;
width: 50px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to also apply a height and width in the css for the image. If it changes per image then apply height and width in the same class as the background image. If it is always the same height/width apply it in a shared class. I'd also suggest to add a src on the img and use a transparent gif as the image. You should also apply an alt tag on the img, use the title as the text.